# UploadedFile __toString() exception

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I'm trying to insert to database (store function) and I'm getting this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__toString() must not throw an exception

/home/vagrant/Sites/mySite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Database;

use PDO;
use Closure;
use Exception;
use Throwable;
use LogicException;
use RuntimeException; // Highlighted
use DateTimeInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection as DoctrineConnection;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as QueryBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder as SchemaBuilder;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar as QueryGrammar;

Arguments
"Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__toString() must not throw an exception"
```

store function

```
/**
 * @param  Request $request
 * @param  ReviewProsConsRepository $reviewProsConsRepository
 * @param  ReviewTextRepository $reviewTextRepository
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function store(Request $request, ReviewProsConsRepository $reviewProsConsRepository, ReviewTextRepository $reviewTextRepository, ReviewLanguageRepository $reviewLanguageRepository, ReviewCurrencyRepository $reviewCurrencyRepository)
{
    $review = $this->reviewRepository->create($request->all()); // Here is the error

    $this->mutualAction($request, $review->id, $reviewProsConsRepository, $reviewTextRepository, $reviewCurrencyRepository, $reviewLanguageRepository);

    return redirect()->route('manager.review.index')->with('message', 'Review criado com sucesso!');
}
```

**-- Edit --**

ReviewRepository.php

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Review;
use Housekeeper\Abilities\Adjustable;
use Housekeeper\Repository;

class ReviewRepository extends Repository
{
    use Adjustable;

    /**
     * Return the name of model that this repository used.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function model()
    {
        return Review::class;
    }

}
```

I have an image upload that returns the **id** from the uploaded image to **cs_upload_id**, but it's getting error and I don't understand why.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The review repository is where the error occurs, that code will be needed.

Comment: I just added the review repository, thanks for the help.

Comment: `$request->all()` will return your uploaded image as an instance of `UploadedFile` - what are you doing with that object?

Comment: @EduardoPierettiUmpierre I think Devon wanted to see what the create method is doing

Answer (score 0):

Not acquainted with the repository package you are using but I'm guessing it's throwing an error because you're simply passing the `reviewRepository->create()` method `$request->all()` which will consist of text key pairs which may be fine to process to the DB but will also include `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` which it can figure out how to handle.

What I would recommend is that you prepare the data in a way that the `reviewRepository->create()` method can understand rather than just passing it the `$request->all()` and hoping it will handle it just fine.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'll try to do what you recommended. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Don't you want to upload the image to your file system also?